# Calling C function which returns function pointer using dart FFI

Tags: dart, ffi

I am using dart:ffi to call C++ functions.
I have following code in C++

```
typedef void* (*unmanaged_callback_ptr)(const char* , const char*);
typedef char* (*managed_direct_method_ptr)(const char*, 
    const char* , unmanaged_callback_ptr);
```

methods as follows which uses function pointer as returns type or as argument

```
CPPLIB_API managed_direct_method_ptr CreateManagedDelegate(const char* libName, 
const char* type,
const char* methodName);

CPPLIB_API char* InvokeManagedFunction(const char* name,
 const char* args,
 unmanaged_callback_ptr unmanagedCallback);
```

Question is how do I call these methods using dart:ffi ?
I mean how to define typedefs, lookup method and fetch the result when function returning function ptr i.e. say `managed_direct_method_ptr` returned by `CreateManagedDelegate(..)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the solution for my problem. So following are typedefs for the C++ methods

```
// typefefs for method 'CreateManagedDelegate' which returns managed_direct_method_ptr
typedef get_create_d = Pointer<NativeFunction<managed_direct_method>> Function(
    Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>);
typedef getCreateD = Pointer<NativeFunction<managed_direct_method>> Function(
    Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>);

// Typedefs of managed_direct_method
typedef managed_direct_method = Pointer<Utf8> Function(
    Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<NativeFunction<unmanaged_call_back>>);
typedef managedDirectMethodDart = Pointer<Utf8> Function(
    Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<NativeFunction<unmanaged_call_back>>);

// These are typedefs for actual function in C++ for which function ptr is defined
typedef unmanaged_call_back = Int32 Function(Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>);
typedef unmanagedCallBackDart = int Function(Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>);
```

Now how to use this typedefs for calling function which returns function ptr is as follows. I have already have handle to DLL as dyLib

```
// Get create_d which returns managed_direct_method_ptr
getCreateD createD = dyLib
      .lookup<NativeFunction<get_create_d>>('CreateManagedDelegate')
      .asFunction();

..... // Assume that args to pass in method are defined as String<Utf8> 

Pointer<NativeFunction<managed_direct_method>> directMethodPtr =
      createD(managedLib, mType, methodName);

  managedDirectMethodDart directMethod = directMethodPtr.asFunction();

// Now call the function using function ptr 
Pointer<NativeFunction<unmanaged_call_back>> fptr =     
      bridgeLib.lookup('unmanagedCallback');

final outList = directMethod(methodName, ''.toNativeUtf8(), fptr).toDartString();
```

Instead of returning function pointer, one can just return a bool as status and set up function pointer inside the C++ method which can be member of class/struct.

Using this approach also you can avoid all above stuff and make it more simpler.
As this is working for me, I am marking it as 'Solved'